# Using Node Red to display the size of database from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-red

I am trying to measure the size of a MySQL database and display it using a gauge on Node Red. Im having issues pulling out the size data of the database and im not sure what to do. Here is my flow.

The code for function above

```
msg.payload = "FROM demoopcua IMPORT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)"
return msg;
```

Code for function below

```
SELECT
test dump AS `Database`,
TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
information_schema.TABLES
ORDER BY
(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC;
msg.payload = "FROM demoopcua IMPORT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)"
return msg;
```

Flow:

```
[{"id":"a98232e2.89bb4","type":"tab","label":"Data Storage ","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"f50611a.320baf","type":"mysql","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","mydb":"f1e0508e.13503","name":"db","x":530,"y":160,"wires":[["73e15eff.866b3"]]},{"id":"74e136d4.61f2d8","type":"function","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","func":"msg.payload = \"FROM demoopcua IMPORT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)\"\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":370,"y":160,"wires":[["f50611a.320baf"]]},{"id":"7d520566.c4a62c","type":"function","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"IntoCloud","func":"msg.topic = msg.payload\nmsg.topic = 'INSERT INTO demoopcua (demotemp, demohumi) VALUES (?,?);';\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":360,"y":100,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"73e15eff.866b3","type":"debug","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":700,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"baa9ee76.4e958","type":"inject","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":220,"y":160,"wires":[["74e136d4.61f2d8","178b8bb7.49ead4"]]},{"id":"178b8bb7.49ead4","type":"function","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","func":" SELECT\ntest dump AS `Database`,\nTABLE_NAME AS `Table`,\nROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`\nFROM\ninformation_schema.TABLES\nORDER BY\n(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)\nDESC;\nmsg.payload = \"FROM demoopcua IMPORT ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)\"\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":5,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":360,"y":220,"wires":[["f50611a.320baf"]]},{"id":"f1e0508e.13503","type":"MySQLdatabase","name":"","host":"127.0.0.1","port":"3306","db":"test dump","tz":"","charset":"UTF8"}]
```

[image: Workflow]

Comment: Edit the question to show (the text, not a screen shot) of what is in the 2 function nodes then we don't have load a random flow just to see what it does

Comment: Especially since the flow you have posted only contains the db node and nothing else.

Comment: i am so sorry for the inconvenience. i have updated the code and plcaed the pictures of the function codes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the second function is not valid (hence the little red triangle) since you can't just include a QUERY in the function like that. Everything has to be valid JavaScript code.

Next, from the [node-red-node-mysql](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-mysql) doc:

> The `msg.topic` must hold the query for the database, and the result is returned in `msg.payload`.

So the correct format should be something like:

```
msg.topic = "SELECT test dump AS `Database`, " +
  "TABLE_NAME AS `Table`, " +
  "ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)` " + 
  "FROM information_schema.TABLES "
  "ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;"

return msg;
```

Comment: Hello Hardillb i ran the code but still faced errors. 

`Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Database`, demoopcua AS `Table`, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 102...' at line 1`

Comment: I made no comment on if your SQL was right (but it's probably because there is a space between `test dump` and it's not wrapped in quotes), just what needed to be done for it to be consumed by the MYSQL node. You will need to debug the SQL yourself or ask a separate question, with the right tags